# finding the biggest value for a set of digits(JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, while-loop

I saw a challenge today which was the following:for a given number X find the biggest number that has the same set of digits as X
. 
Here is a code that I tried. It stops after the for loop, it is supposed to add the string of numbers in an array.
*The code has comments if you aren't sure about something don't hesitate to ask me.

```
//we give the variable a number 
 var num = 1263;
 document.write(num+ "<br>");
//we turn the number into a string and store it into X
 var X =num.toString();
 document.write(X+ "<br>");
//we split the digits of the number (ie from X)
 var eachChar = X.split("");
 document.write(eachChar+ "<br>");
 //we sort the numbers in order of increasing value
 eachChar.sort().reverse();
 document.write(eachChar+ "<br>");
 //add the strings together 
 for (i = 0; i < eachChar.length; i++) {
    eachchar[0] = eachChar[0]+eachChar[i+1];

 }
//it stops working from here on
//turn the number back into an integer
 TurnBack =parseInt(eachChar[0]);

 if (num=TurnBack) {
    document.write("the initial value is the highest value");

 }else{
     document.write("the biggest possible value is"+ TurnBack);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two simple errors in your code.

1. `eachchar[0] = ...` has a capitalization typo. It should be `eachChar[0] = ...`
2. Your last check is using a single `=` instead of a comparison operator like `==` or `===`. It should be `if (num === turnBack)`, otherwise you are *setting* the value of `num`, not *comparing* it.

That in mind, there are certainly simpler (or at least more concise) ways of writing this. Your logic is sound, but you might be able to clean it up a bit by chaining your methods together. Furthermore, you're iterating through the array to rebuild the string, but there's a built-in method for this: [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const checkHighestNumber = num => {
  const highest = parseInt(num.toString().split('').sort().reverse().join(""));
  return highest === num
    ? `Initial value is the highest value.`
    : `The largest possible number from ${num} is ${highest}`;
}

console.log(checkHighestNumber(54321));
console.log(checkHighestNumber(12431));
```